# Freeform field description in template?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I see in the "New Field" dialog that the field description "can be inserted into your forms" but I don't see any documentation on how to do it.

I tried guessing with "{composer:field_description}" inside the {composer:fields} pair, but no luck.

I should clarify that the reason I want to use field descriptions this way is to enable content editors to add some descriptive text about a field below the label.  And they need to be able to do everything using the Composer interface.

I am open to alternative solutions that meet this requirement.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
{freeform:description:{composer:field_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
{freeform:description:MY-FIELD-NAME}
```